# How to modify user information in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to modify the user's data and I want that if he does not change his password that we can keep his old password.

Here is what I did in terms of form (Request)

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nom'=>'required',
            'prenom'=>'required',
            'username'=>'required',
            'nom'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
            'groupe'=>'required',
            //'password'=>'min:6',
            'cpassword'=> 'same:password|min:6',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Consider asking your question in English, you would reach more people and you would not get downvoted

Comment: You removed the rule definition to validate the password entry. Why would that skip saving the password? The old password is already kept if the user doesn't change it. What makes you think that doesn't happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: By the way I want that if the user decides to modify the information of his profile, when he arrives at the password level and he does not enter anything in the field; so that you can keep your old password.